# Enterprise java app architecture. Dynamic domain model

Tags: java, system-design, domain-model

I wonder what is the best way to implement dynamic domain model persisted in SQL database?
Saying dynamic domain model I mean such model when user can change "class" of object by adding  or removing properties.

For example: little internet shop where manager can add new types of product with web-interface.
Should I use something like Map everywhere? Maybe it is better to keep only dynamic part of object in Map? Or maybe runtime class generation will help? Or I should take a tour over dynamic languages like Groovy? I have tested first and second methods and this is real headache to develop in such way.

What is the common practise?

Comment: Might be a better topic for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The fact that a manager can add a new type of product doesn't mean your model is dynamic. It means you have a Product entity which as a many-to-one association to a ProductType entity (a product table with a foreign key to a product_type table, in RDBMS terms)

Comment: Sorry for offtop but what is difference between stackoverflow and Programmers?

Comment: Yeah. Thats what I've done: declare fields in ProductType entity. But how I should deal with it in my code? If manager have created new ProductType should I generate new java-class for it with cglib magic?

Comment: @AlexPovar, You would then add a new row in the table that corresponds to the ProductType entity. Then you can create new rows in the Product table that correspond to the new ProductType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a 1 to 1 from product to product type.  So product has a member var called productType.  You'll also have a 1-to-many from product to features.  So the product class will have a list of features.

I can't imagine a more wrong way to do this then using cglib to create classes on the fly.